# Finding and replacing parameters in an HTML txt folder

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, replace, export-to-csv

I have a database, I don't know if you'd call it a data base but it's getting there, we have multiple URL's from the old companies files which are of chaos. I want to find and replace a .txt file of multiple URL's with the companies new banners/HTML information. This script will work in conjunction with the other data frame program's written in Python (CVS parser). Here is my code. Why is my .TXT file not being replaced?

I have tried looking into the output of the read object which I know is a string. As well as looking into the functionality of the function replace().

```
    import json
    import csv


    class HTML_Parser:
        def _init_(self, data):
            data.self = data

    F = open(r"C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Emeran-Parser\HTMLtoBeReplaced.txt", 
    "r")

    str1 = F.read()







 str1.replace("http://www.ultrarev.com/processedimages/ebay_layout/banner750x150     .jpg","https://xcart.amcoautoparts.com/ebay_layout/ebay_tmp_top.jpg")

 str1.replace("http://www.ultrarev.com/processedimages/manufacturers/Ultrarev- 
   Footer.jpg","https://xcart.amcoautoparts.com/manufacturers/Ultrarev-F 
   ooter.jpg")
    str1.replace("ULTRAREV INC.","AMCO Auto Parts, LLC")
    str1.replace("ULTRAREV INC",'AMCO Auto Parts, LLC')
    str1.replace("Should you have any question  please call 1(877) 858- 
   7272.","Should you have any question, please message us!")
    str1.replace("120 Central Ave. Farmingdale  NJ 07727"," ")
    str1.replace("CALL FOR CUSTOMER SUPPORT"," ")
    str1.replace("Please Call us toll free 1-877-858-7272!","Should you have any 
    question, please message us!")
    str1.replace('<a style="color: #000000; font-weight:bold; text- 
    decoration:none" href="tel:732-938-3999">'," ")
    str1.replace('<a style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: 
    none" href="tel:1-877-858-7272">1-877-858-7272</a>',' ')
    str1.replace('<a style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: 
    none" href="tel:732-938-3999">732-938-3999</a>',' ')
    str1.replace(' OR ',' ')
    str1.replace('OEM (Match Case) - Find them in both Title and Description', 
    'OE')
    str1.replace("http://www.ultrarev.com", "https://xcart.amcoautoparts.com")
    str1.replace('http://www.ultrarev.com/processedimages/manufacturers/ralco- 
   rz- 
     logo_texture.png', 'http://amcoautoparts.com/images/P/RalcoRZLogo.png')



print(str1)
```

I expect it to return a string with the replaced values instead it returns values of the prior string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just appended all of the replaces.

```
import json
import csv


class HTML_Parser:
    def _init_(self, data):
        data.self = data

F = open(r"C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Emeran-Parser\HTMLtoBeReplaced.txt")

str1 = F.read()

str2 = str1.replace("http://www.ultrarev.com/processedimages/ebay_layout/banner750x150.jpg","https://xcart.amcoautoparts.com/ebay_layout/ebay_tmp_top.jpg").replace("http://www.ultrarev.com/processedimages/manufacturers/Ultrarev-Footer.jpg","https://xcart.amcoautoparts.com/manufacturers/Ultrarev-Footer.jpg").replace("ULTRAREV INC.","AMCO Auto Parts, LLC").replace("ULTRAREV INC",'AMCO Auto Parts, LLC').replace("Should you have any question  please call 1(877) 858-7272.","Should you have any question, please message us!").replace("120 Central Ave. Farmingdale  NJ 07727"," ").replace("CALL FOR CUSTOMER SUPPORT"," ").replace("Please Call us toll free 1-877-858-7272!","Should you have any question, please message us!").replace('<a style="color: #000000; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none" href="tel:732-938-3999">'," ").replace('<a style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none" href="tel:1-877-858-7272">1-877-858-7272</a>',' ').replace('<a style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none" href="tel:732-938-3999">732-938-3999</a>',' ').replace(' OR ',' ').replace('OEM (Match Case) - Find them in both Title and Description', 'OE').replace("http://www.ultrarev.com", "https://xcart.amcoautoparts.com").replace('http://www.ultrarev.com/processedimages/manufacturers/ralco-rz-logo_texture.png', 'http://amcoautoparts.com/images/P/RalcoRZLogo.png')



print(str2)
```

That seems to be the best solution for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace()` does not modify the original string - instead it returns new one with replacements done.

You have to chain your calls. Something like:

```
new_str = original_str.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)
```

Also I suggest that you use tuple to store replacement pairs like this:

```
replaces = (('from1', 'to1'), ('from2', 'to2'), ('from3', 'to3'))
for src, dest in replaces:
  str1 = str1.replace(src, dest)
print (str1)
```

Comment: Oh yea I forgot - Python many times just returns new instances of the object instead of modifying the original. My Pythonic way of thinking still needs fine tuning. Thank you. I mean besides the HUGE line of replaces what do you suggest? A for loop perhaps? Plus this will help me down the line with other issues.